# How can I avoid AUCTeX wrongly inferring the language of a document?

Tags: auctex, french

A colleague using a class I wrote reports
that AUCTeX is inserting guillemets when he hits the double-quote key. Investigation showed that `TeX-language-fr-hook` is being called even though the document itself is not in French.

If I understand a comment from @egreg in response to my colleague's question ([Double-quote produces guillemets in emacs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177031/double-quote-produces-guillemets-in-emacs))
the reason AUCTeX thinks the comment is in French might be something like `\usepackage[french]{babel}`.

In fact there is this code in the class: `\iffrench
\RequirePackage[english,francais]{babel}\fi`
This conditional branch is only triggered if the `french` option to our class is chosen by the user. It seems that AUCTeX is taking that line to mean that the document is in French, regardless. How can I arrange it so the `\usepackage` is hidden from AUCTeX or only has an effect when it's intended to?

For full context see
[Double-quote produces guillemets in emacs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177031/double-quote-produces-guillemets-in-emacs)

**Edit:** Below are a few lines from the `*Messages*` buffer in emacs that may be useful in tracing the problem:

```
Loading /var/lib/auctex/emacs24/msp.elc...done
Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/auctex/style/babel.el (source)...done
Loading /var/lib/auctex/emacs24/francais.elc...done
Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/auctex/style/francais.el (source)...done
Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/auctex/style/frenchb.el (source)...done
Loading /var/lib/auctex/emacs24/english.elc...done
```

Comment: AUCTeX doesn't know much about TeX conditionals.  Could you please post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/31416) anyway?

Comment: Can you write an e-lisp hack that turns off the hook for just this document?

Comment: Wow, welcome to TeX.sx, sir! We are not worthy, we are not worthy.

Comment: I would guess you can hide the `\usepackage` in a class it would be better to use `\RequirePackage` anyway (it's the same thing but auctex may not know that:-) or `\@nameuse{RequirePackage}[french]{babel}` or...

Comment: Thanks David and Paulo for the welcome.   It's good to be among friends.  Giordano, I'll try to provide an MWE but the problem is that the behavior does not happen for me (even though I use auctex too), only for my colleague.  Thanks for the suggestion Ethan Bolker - one can write an elisp hack to do just about anything, but the problem is not "this document" -- according to MTS any document using this class triggers the behavior!  So I'd prefer to solve the problem at the class level.

Comment: Thanks David - in fact what the class says is `\RequirePackage[french]{babel}`.  When I posted the question I was piggybacking on a suggestion in the other posting and I didn't check carefully.  I've now corrected my posting.  We'll see what MTS says about \@nameuse.

Comment: My guess: your colleague has an auto-generated style file for that class, you don't, this is why s/he always load `style/french.el`.  Removing `"french"` from run hooks in her/his auto-generated style file should suffice.

Comment: @giordano, this happens even when I run `emacs -q`, so it seems that my custom settings are not the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, changing the `\usepackage` command to `\@nameuse{RequirePackage}[french]{babel}` didn't fix the problem either.

Comment: @MTS  Do you have or not the auto-generated style file?  I've never said that custom settings should count here.

Comment: @giordano, ah, sorry, I misinterpreted your question. I don't know anything about auto-generated style files. How do I check whether I have one or not?

Comment: @MTS in my setup in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.86/style/` i have lisp versions of various latex packages including babel.el do you have anywhere in your load path a lisp version of the class

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.87.5/style/babel.el` I have babel.el (and babel.elc).

Comment: @MTS no I meant do you have a saved lisp version of the  custom class if you use `\documentclass{wibble}` and auctex has a `wibble.el` that says it's french it will do that whatever the tex code actually does unless you force things back in sync

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. No, there is no lisp version of the class that I can find.

Comment: @MTS  The auto-generated file is placed in the `auto/` subdirectory of the directory in which the class file is situated.

Comment: @giordano There is no `auto/` subdirectory there; the class file is in a subdirectory of `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/`, where I don't have write permission as a regular user.

Comment: @MTS  Ok, but somewhere there should be a style file triggering the loading of `french.el`.  How is called this class?  Following David's example, if it's called `wibble`, after opening your document visit the `*Messages*` buffer, there should be a line `Loading /path/to/wibble.el...done`.  Where is the style file?

Comment: @giordano I've added a few of those lines in the question itself, but the change needs to be reviewed, as I don't have enough reputation to edit it myself.

Comment: @MTS  Thank you, I added an answer to this question.  Having the class file or at least the `/var/lib/auctex/emacs24/msp.elc` would help, but the answer should work anyway.

Comment: I usually set `TeX-parse-self` and `TeX-auto-save` to nil in .emacs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `*Messages*` log I deduce the "offending" class is `msp.cls`.  Unfortunately I can't find it on the Internet to test it, but anyway in the `/var/lib/auctex/emacs24/msp.elc` file there should be a `"french"` string somewhere.  Just remove it (you'll need to edit it with root privileges, from within Emacs issue <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> `/sudo::/var/lib/auctex/emacs24/msp.elc` <kbd>RET</kbd> to open it) and you should be done.

Comment: Giordano, thanks.  I've not placed msp.cls on the internet because it's not meant for general use.   

You gave a good solution for the user of the class.  However the writer of the class (me) would love for other users to be spared the same confusion.  Maybe David Carlisle's suggestion of replacing `\RequirePackage` by `\@nameuse` works, and I would like to test it; but I don't know under what circumstances msp.elc is generated. (MTS is reporting it was not regenerated after he deleted it.)

Comment: @SilvioLevy  It can be re-generated by issuing `M-x TeX-auto-generate RET' on the `msp.cls` buffer or, to re-generate all style files (it will take a while), `sudo emacs -batch -f TeX-auto-generate-global` in the command line.

Comment: Bingo.  Either `\@nameuse` or `\csname` prevent `francais` from being added to msp.el -- so I'll incorporate that change to the class.

Comment: Yes, AUCTeX parser doesn't know that syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Giordano and David Carlisle who provided the key information, here is a complete answer.  In the package file, replace `\RequirePackage[english,francais]{babel}` by `\@nameuse{RequirePackage}[english,francais]{babel}`.  Now when your user's auctex compiles the file (which you can also do within emacs, for testing, with `M-x TeX-auto-generate`), the string `francais` will no longer appear in the output (which is typically placed in `~/.emacs.d/auctex/auto/msp.el`), and all will be well.